# Prevent GridView to add duplicate entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

THe following code display the validation message "File already in the list" if the file already exist however it is not preventing it from adding to gridview. Would be able to advise what is wrong. Thank you

```
if (GridFiles.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int count = GridFiles.Rows.Count;
    dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dcFileName = new DataColumn("File Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add(dcFileName);

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        if (GridFiles.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text == FileName)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "File already in the list";
            break;
        }

    }

    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["File Name"] = GridFiles.Rows[k].Cells[1].Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }


    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["File Name"] = FileName;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    GridFiles.DataSource = dt;
    ViewState["grdContent"] = dt; //stored datable in viewstate
    GridFiles.DataBind();
}

else
{
    dt = new DataTable();

    DataColumn dcFileName = new DataColumn("File Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add(dcFileName);
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["File Name"] = FileName;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    GridFiles.DataSource = dt;
    ViewState["grdContent"] = dt; //stored datable in viewstate
    GridFiles.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hi Grant, i have update the post. I mean validation message not exception. thank you

Comment: Gridviews really just display data, if you set a primary key on the underling data table the problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the *easiest* thing to do to get this working is to replace `break;` with `return;`.

Instead of breaking out of the `for` loop, you'll just set the error message on the label and leave the method.

---

You could also replace the first `for` loop with a LINQ statement:

```
if (myGrid.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Any(x => x.Cells[1].Text == FileName))
{
    lblMessage.Text = "File already in the list";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two `for` loops. You break out of the first one if it has the same filename, but then you still go into the next `for` loop and add it.

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
{
    if (GridFiles.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text == FileName)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "File already in the list";
        break;
    }
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["File Name"] = GridFiles.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```